# Homotopy equivalence between equator of $n$-sphere and southern hemisphere minus an open set.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I want to prove that the embedding of the equator of an $n$-sphere which is homeomorphic to a sphere $S^{n-1}$ into the southern hemisphere denoted as $D^{n}_{-}$ minus the set $U= 
\{ (x_0,\dots, x_n) \in S^n :x_n < -1/2  \} $ is a homotopy equivalence. I tried to play a bit with the steoreographic projection but to no avail. It somehow seems true that embedding a "circle" into a cylinder like shape makes this work.

Comment: How do you show an annulus deformation retracts to its inner (or outer) boundary?

Comment: I tried building a homotopy to any inner "circle" that slides every point of my annulus to the required circle but I couldn't get the hang of the formula of the homotopy.

Comment: Slides how? If you want a formula, you need a specific recipe.

Comment: Hint: it looks like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rceil2dga8). Drag the parameter $s \in [0, 1]$ to witness the (strong) deformation retract of the southern tropics (your subspace) onto the equator.

Comment: I guess I could try the map $H : D^{n}_{-} - U \times I \rightarrow D^{n}_{-} - U$ by sending $((x_0,\dots,x_n),t)$ to $(x_0, \dots ,tx_n) $. If that works my only problem would be continuity.

Comment: Big hint: Project $D-U$ onto the plane $x_n=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A  = \{y  \in \mathbb R^n \mid \sqrt 3/2  \le \lVert y \rvert \le 1 \}$ be the closed spherical shell with center $0$, inner radius $\sqrt 3/2$ and outer radius $1$.

1. The map $r : A \to S^{n-1}, r(y) = y /\lVert y \rvert$, is a strong defomation retraction. Thus the inlusion $i : S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow A$ is a homotopy equivalence.
2. The projection $p : D^n_- \setminus U \to A, p(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, is a homeomorphism. Its inverse is given by $p^{-1}(y) = (y,-\sqrt{1 - \lVert y \rvert^2})$.
3. The embeddingn $j : S^{n-1} \to D^n_-  \setminus U, i(z) = (z,0)$ is a homotopy equivalence because $j = p^{-1} \circ i$.